# Python3 Prophet model predict() throws TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort' when used with holidays dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I have been trying to fit a prophet model. The predict() function worked fine when i just did quick dirty run without adding any holidays. But as soon as i added a holidays dataset (prophet(holidays=holiday_train).fit(train_data)) the predict function started throwing following error.

TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort'

Can anyone help me fix it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You are probably using a version of `pandas<0.23.0` and `sort` was added in version `0.23.0`. However, the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/master/python/requirements.txt) requires `pandas>=0.20.1` The issues looks like it is this function:

```
 def construct_holiday_dataframe(self, dates):` 

            . . . 

    all_holidays = pd.concat((all_holidays, country_holidays_df), sort=False)

            . . .
```

Check out the [docs](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/master/python/fbprophet/forecaster.py#L436).

Looks like they need to update their requirements.txt to be `pandas>=0.23.0`